# Jena Result set to String

Tags: java, string, jena, dbpedia

I'm using jena to query dbpedia and I return a ResultSet, how can I make the ResultSet returned to a java String? I don't want it in JSON format.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the Apache Jena [ResultSetFormatter](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ResultSetFormatter.html) documentation - the "asText" method may be what you're looking for:

```
ResultSet results = ...
String resultsAsString = ResultSetFormatter.asText(results);
```